# How to Import consistently in Python (IDE Inspection import paths not same for test runners)

Tags: python-3.x, import, pycharm

Python import rules have always confused me. I hope someone can explain this in
simple terms.

I have the following Python3 directory layout from the 'Testing Python' book 
by David Sale.

I am running Python3.7 on MacOS Mojave and using PyCharm 2019.2 .

```
bank
├── __init__.py
├── bank
│   ├── account.py
│   ├── bank.py
│   └── bank_app.py
├── templates
└── test
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bdd
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── features
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── bank.feature
    │   └── steps *
    │       └── steps.py
    └── unit
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── account_test.py
        └── bank_test.py

(* can be ignored as not using lettuce but aloe pkg for python3)
```

**bank/bank/bank.py**:

```
from bank.bank.account import Account
```

**bank/test/unit/bank_test.py**:

```
from bank.bank.bank import Bank
from bank.bank.account import Account
```

**bank/test/unit/account_test.py**:

```
from bank.bank.account import Account
```

**bank/test/bdd/features/__init__.py**:   (for acceptance tests but seen by unittest runners)

```
from bank.bank.bank_app import app
```

From the command line I can run the unit tests successfully:

> nosetests --rednose -v

The acceptance tests also pass:

> aloe --rednose -v

However, PyCharm reports `Unresolved Reference ...` for each above imported module unless I remove the leading pkg:

```
from bank.bank import Bank
from bank.account import Account
```

but if I do this the test runners will fail.
The runners will also fail if I remove the __init__.py files but python3 does not need these?

I believe this is because runners being external tools require the paths to be absolute, but PyCharm paths are relative from the pkg.

**Q**: How can I make PyCharm and the command line work with common import paths?

In an attempt to fix this I have tried (to no avail) adding the following to **bank/__init__.py**:

```
import importlib
pkg = importlib.import_module('bank')
# check if it's all there..
def bla(mod):
    print(dir(mod))
bla(pkg)
```

However, when I run this from the command line I see no **bank** module:

> python3 __init__.py

```
['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']
```

**EDIT**
Adding a nosetests runner configuration to PyCharm has the same requirements as the nosetests runner running from the command line.
It is only the PyCharm IDE Inspection that complains about the import paths.

**EDIT**
My projects interpreter is the system interpreter: /usr/local/bin/python3.7
nosetests and aloe are also system-wide.

They do not have any problems using other system wide modules that my project imports, i.e. flask.

Investigated this after finding this post on PyTest (that I am not using):
https://medium.com/@dirk.avery/pytest-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-requests-a770e6926ac5

In which he talks about system-wide vs virtual-environment modules.

Jan '18
*"If you have installed pytest system-wide, in other words, outside of a virtual environment, pytest has a nasty habit of only looking outside your virtual environment for modules! If your project is using a module that is only installed in your virtual environment, and you’re using a system-wide pytest, it won’t find the module, even if you’ve activated the virtual environment."*

**EDIT (Possible solution)**

Add relative imports to new file:

**bank/bank/__init__.py**

```
from .account import Account
from .bank import Bank
```

This makes the PyCharm Inspection happy for the unit test files.

Change the unit test imports to:

**bank/test/unit/account_test.py**

```
from bank import Account
```

**bank/test/unit/bank_test.py**

```
from bank import Account
from bank import Bank
```

Then add relative imports to:

**bank/__init__.py**

```
from .bank.account import Account
from .bank.bank import Bank
```

and change the production file imports to:

**bank/bank/bank.py**

```
from .account import Account
```

**NOTE** I haven't got this to work for the bank/test/bdd/features/__init__.py file, I still use absolute imports, and for aloe I've had to move the bank/bank/bank_app.py up one level so as to see the bank/templates/ folder.

**bank/bank.py**

```
from bank.bank import Bank
```

Comment: "PyCharm reports Unresolved Reference ... for each above imported module unless I remove the leading pkg"  Had you already imported `bank` by doing `import bank`? Because then any import starting with "bank" would be relative to that module, which would require dropping 1 "bank" from the import path.

Comment: No, the imports you see above are my only imports for bank modules.
I ensured I removed the edit to **bank/__init__.py** also with the same results.

Comment: What I think is, you have opened your pycharm project in the bank folder.

Comment: No, when I open the project I navigate to the top level bank/ folder and tell PyCharm to open that. The project layout above is what I see in the IDE.